# How to execute a command in (from) zabbix aws elbv2

Tags: amazon-web-services, zabbix

How to execute a command in (from) zabbix `UserParameter=alb.co[*],aws elbv2 describe-listener-certificates --listener-arn *******` in sudores.d in file zabbix `Defaults:zabbix !requiretty zabbix ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL`
the command is not executed.
Added credential (macros) to Template

```
<zabbix_export>
    <version>5.0</version>
    <date>2020-07-24T10:52:10Z</date>
    <groups>
        <group>
            <name>Templates</name>
        </group>
    </groups>
    <templates>
        <template>
            <template>Template alb-co</template>
            <name>Template ssl-count</name>
            <groups>
                <group>
                    <name>Templates</name>
                </group>
            </groups>
            <applications>
                <application>
                    <name>alb-co</name>
                </application>
            </applications>
            <items>
                <item>
                    <name>alb-co</name>
                    <key>alb.co[arn,{$HOST.DNS},--access-key{$AWS_ACCESS_KEY},--secret-key{$AWS_SECRET_KEY},--region{$REGION}]</key>
                    <delay>30s</delay>
                    <applications>
                        <application>
                            <name>alb-co</name>
                        </application>
                    </applications>
                    <triggers>
                        <trigger>
                            <expression>{last()}&gt;=23</expression>
                            <name>{ITEM.LASTVALUE} alb-co {HOST.DNS}</name>
                            <priority>INFO</priority>
                            <manual_close>YES</manual_close>
</trigger>
                    </triggers>
                </item>
            </items>
            <macros>
                <macro>
                    <macro>{$AWS_ACCESS_KEY}</macro>
                    <type>SECRET_TEXT</type>
                </macro>
                <macro>
                    <macro>{$AWS_SECRET_KEY}</macro>
                    <type>SECRET_TEXT</type>
                </macro>
                <macro>
                    <macro>{$REGION}</macro>
                    <value>eu-central-1</value>
                </macro>
            </macros>
        </template>
    </templates>
</zabbix_export>
```

But still doesn't work.
There are no item and trigger errors, it just returns the value 0,
but should 26. Maybe someone started with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closed issue, granted permission to read instance ELB